# Inner Join Sql para un query de dos tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos estoy trantando de hacer un query en donde obtenga elementos de diferentes tablas, en esta caso, solo es para 2 , me imagino que puedo usar un **Inner Join** pero por lo que entiendo esto me sirve para relacionar tablas. Esto es más o menos lo que quiero ...

```
select e.razon ,l.conf from eventos e
join listainvitados l
where idlistainvitados = 1
```

Comment: sql server señor :3

Comment: estoy obteniendo un error y por lo que entiendo con join debo sustuir un valor de la tabla por otro

Comment: ese join esta mal escrito, por eso... igual, si recibis un error deberias mostrar cual es

Comment: Necesita un "on" antes del "where" para juntarlos sobre un valor común, como "join listainvitados l on e.id = l.id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas tener un valor común entre ambas relaciones (tablas).

Generalmente, cuando se trata de un EQUIJOIN (en el 99% de los casos será así), tu query lucirá a algo parecido a esto:

```
select e.razon ,l.conf from eventos e
  inner join listainvitados l on (e.evento_id = l.evento_id)
  where idlistainvitados = 1
```

O bien, usando la sintaxis `using` que es la que yo siempre prefiero:

```
select e.razon ,l.conf from eventos e
  inner join listainvitados l using (evento_id)
  where idlistainvitados = 1
```

Comment: using en sql server? no lo vi nunca

Comment: `using` no existe para SQL Server, a menos que sea un *feature* que se acaba de agregar

Comment: @gbianchi, es de mysql, creo que Pablo no registró el cambio de etiqueta.

Comment: de acuerdo @PatricioMoracho..:)

Comment: tengo una ultima pregunta, qué pasa si a todo esto quisiera agregarle un **count**, es decir contar todos los registros, como sería?